# Determine big o for these functions

Tags: big-o, computer-science

For the below two questions, solution manual states that for
b. O(n log n)
c. O(n log n)

But as per my understanding b is O(log n) and C is sqrt(n).

[image]

Comment: What about your "understanding" leads to these conclusions?

Comment: @ScottHunter because first one is 50 log n + 2n log (n). Clearly it is class n log n but doesnt the n>2 affect? Also second one, is log (n log n). Dont we consider the outer part as it is log only compared to n^0.5

Comment: What does `log(n>2)` mean?

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ScottHunter i would appreciate you helping in explanation rather than testing me out. This discussion is not going anywhere. I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Who is getting credit for the class this is for?  And you can't explain the question, of what value would any answer I gave you be?

Comment: "Clearly it is class n log n" and yet you answered log n.

Comment: if you have log(n log ), do we go through the inside or outside ? in this case wont we considered the outer expression as dominant because its on the outer or doesn't matter?

Comment: Not sure I follow; log(n log n) > log(n), but much less than log(n^n) or n log(n), and no more than sqrt(n) I think, though a proof eludes me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you on (c).  `O(c(n))` is `O(sqrt(n))`.  `n^n = e^(n log n)`, so `log log (n^n)` is `log(n) + log log(n)`.  The square root grows much faster than this.

For (b), I'm interpreting `log(n > 2)` to mean `log(n)`, where n > 2.  Maybe I'm wrong.  In which case the second term is `O(n log n)` which is bigger than the `5 log(n ^ 10) = 50 log(n)` of the first term.